# Estimate laser diode beam quality from datasheet

Tags: optics, laser

I want the estimate the minimum divergence angle that can be obtained when collimating the beam coming from a laser diode. For this I intent to use the following equation from https://www.rp-photonics.com/beam_divergence.html:

$\theta = M^2 \frac{\lambda}{\pi w_0}$

Unfortunately it seems that laser diode datasheets never provide a $M^2$ value. My question is, would it be valid to estimate $M^2$ using this same equation and substituting the size of the emitting area for $w_0$ and divergence angle provided in the datasheet for $\theta$?

Comment: Have you tried it? You can google typical M² of laser diodes and see if it makes sense. Do not forget that $w_0$ is radius.

Comment: I am aware that I need to convert to radius yes. I have indeed tried doing this and the numbers don't look outrageous, but I can't really find much typical values to compare with on google. Most sources simply indicate that the $M^2$ of high-power diodes (such as the ones I am looking at)  tend to be "bad" without giving typical numbers. So I guess my real question if whether or not the emitting area of a diode can be considered as being the waste of the (approximately) gaussian beam coming from it?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not my field, I cannot really answer that. On a first approximation I would do it exactly like that to estimate the M². And just like I said I would try to find any source to which I could compare what I got and see if it made sense.